# Adding new map to current project using ArcGIS Pro .NET SDK?

Tags: c#, .net, arcgis-pro, arcgis-pro-sdk

The new ArcGIS Pro SDK for .NET is currently in beta for ArcGIS Pro 1.1, and I'm having trouble with map/project objects.

I can add layers to an existing map, but I can't seem to figure out how to add a new map to the project:

```
public async void AddMapToProject()
{
    //create new map and set basemap layer
    Map mymap = new Map("MapName");
    mymap.SetBasemapLayers(Basemap.Oceans);
    //there's also Map.Create("MapName"), not sure which to use

    //access current project
    Project myproject = Project.Current;
    //this doesn't work
    await myproject.AddAsync(mymap);

    //project has AddAsync(Item item) method, but I don't think 
    //this is for adding maps as it doesn't accept a map object and
    //ArcGIS.Desktop.Core.Item.Create(map.uri) doesn't work
}
```

Any ideas? Can't seem to find an example or the correct method anywhere. The API reference for the SDK is [here](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/beta/sdk/api-reference/#topic1.html) but doesn't offer many examples. Couldn't find much in the github samples / community samples either.

Comment: Don't know if this will help but I followed your link and ended up on GitHub, they have some sample code [here](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-pro-sdk-community-samples) which may have an example of the code you require? Have to admit I could not see an obvious route for adding Maps but then I've never used the object model of ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I've gone through all the sample code already and couldn't see what I needed. It seems like such a fundamental thing to do so I'm not quite sure why I'm having so much trouble finding anything. Perhaps it doesn't exist yet in beta...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the beta doc might be a little out of date. I was told to look at the **factory** methods. (`MapFactory.Create`, `ItemFactory.Create`, etc which will be the way to go when the SDK is released at 1.1)

Try this: (note, the map is created in the projectpane, but is not automatically opened)

```
protected override void OnClick()
{          
  var map = AddMap("myMap");  

}
private Task<Map> AddMap(string mapName)
{
    return QueuedTask.Run(() =>
    {
        var map = MapFactory.CreateMap(mapName);
        map.SetName(mapName);              
        return map;                
    });
}
```

Actually, try this nicer code snippet that opens the new map:

```
private async Task<Map> CreateAndOpen(string mapName)
{
    await QueuedTask.Run(() =>
    {
        var map = MapFactory.CreateMap(mapName, basemap: Basemap.ProjectDefault);
        ProApp.Panes.CreateMapPaneAsync(map);
        return map;
    });   
}
```