# Open split view maps using ArcGIG Pro SDK

Tags: arcgis-pro, c#, arcgis-pro-sdk

Related to this question : [Adding new map to current project using ArcGIS Pro .NET SDK?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/153052/adding-new-map-to-current-project-using-arcgis-pro-net-sdk) , however this question is quite old and not exactly what I am looking for.

I want to create an add-in that loads in specific data, but when loading the data (basically on the onclick() method) I would like to have two maps open in split level view, as with the image below.

[image: This image shows what I would like]

Any idea how to make this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I did that:

```
var firstMapPane = DockManager.DocumentWindows.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Title.Contains(firstMapName));
var secondMapPane = DockManager.DocumentWindows.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Title.Contains(secondMapName));

secondMapPane.Dock(firstMapPane, ActiproSoftware.Windows.Controls.Side.Bottom);
```

Comment: Where's the DockManager from?